# Right margin for fancyhdr

Tags: fonts, margins, fancyhdr, thesis, setspace

how can I get the right margin when using fancyhdr and onehalfspacing? 
I am currently writing my thesis, and I am not quite sure if my margins are all right.
Here is an example code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,
%     DIV=calc 
     ]{scrreprt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

\parindent0pt

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]
{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{
 \thechapter.\ #1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]
{\markright{\MakeUppercase{\thesection\ #1}}{}}

\fancyhead[L]{ \leftmark \text{}}
\fancyhead[R]{{\rightmark}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\raggedbottom
\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
\chapter{introduction}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

The compiled version seems to me to have very small margins. I tried to adjust it by adding `DIV=calc`, but then the margins seem to be too large.

Which one is the right way? Maybe someone knows how big the margins should be.

Thank you very much!

Comment: `\MakeUppercase{ \thechapter.\ #1}}` puts a space before the text you may want `\MakeUppercase{\thechapter.\ #1}}`

Comment: You cas see the margins using `\usepackage{showframe}` or `\usepacke[showframe]{geometry}`.

Comment: The problem is, I dont have an instruction regarding the margins. Thus, I would like to adjust the margins in the best possible way. So what is the standard/best way? With DIV=calc? Or without?

Comment: @TomandJerry This is subjective. The KOMA-Script manual has a lengthy discussion about this when it presents `typearea`, but you'll find other rules in books on typography, on the Internet... and it may be that the people who will evaluate your thesis have strange typographic taste (I believe that line spacing is often 1.5 times or twice the normal baseline in thesis formatting guidelines, right?).

Comment: The best way to adjust the margins is to use geometry and ignore KOMA.

Comment: @frougon yes, I am using 1.5 spacing. The problem is I don't have a guideline. I guess I have to size it by myself. But maybe someone has a good advice on how to do it.

Comment: @JohnKormylo and what would you suggest, as parameters?